# Can I Bulk Load Compressed Files into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, bulkinsert

Is there a way to bulk load data from Azure Blob to SQL Server?  I'm accessing the files through Azure Storage Explorer. I'm pretty sure it can be done, but I'm getting an error that says the 'file could not be opened'. Here is my code.

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[dest_table]
FROM ''alldata/2019/06/29/BB/dds_id.out.20190629.gz''
WITH (      FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
            FIRSTROW = 46,
            ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''')';
PRINT @cmd
EXEC(@cmd)
```

The file ends in .gz, so it's compressed. Is that the problem here? More importantly, is there a workaround for this?  All I have is SQL Server; no access to SSIS.

Comment: A compressed file won't be able to be read, no. If you were to open that file in a text editor, you'll see that it looks like nonsense; that's exactly how SQL Server will see it. You'll need to extract the file first.

Comment: Also, `FROM 'alldata/2019/` is not exactly a directory structure that SQL Server will understand.

Comment: Now, it _is_ possible that you could insert the contents of that .gz file as a single blob, and then get the contents out using [the `DECOMPRESS()` built-in function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decompress-transact-sql)... but better to get the file in the right format for proper bulk importing first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you're asking for but the powershell library dba-tools is able to bulk copy gzip compressed CSV files to SQL Server.

Filename just needs to end in `.csv.gz`

https://docs.dbatools.io/Import-DbaCsv.html

Answer (score 0):

The compressed file is not a data file.

The document [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments):

Imports a data file into a database table or view in a user-specified format in SQL Server.

The argument data_file :

> Is the full path of the data file that contains data to import into the specified table or view. BULK INSERT can import data from a disk (including network, floppy disk, hard disk, and so on).

One way is that you uncompress .gz file firstly, and then using BULK INSERT to load the data file to SQL server.

There is another way you can try it using Azure Data Factory. Data Factory can help you uncompress the .gz file in dataset settings:
[image]

Reference this tutorial: [Copy data from Azure Blob storage to a SQL database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly the way I'm doing it now.  I was hoping to get a little more control over the process, so I can add a data into a field, based on a file's name.  I'm working with hundreds of files that have dates in their names.  I wanted to grab all these dates and do an INSERT INTO each table.